# Where to find reference to imported project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project that is referencing an imported project.  I can only see this in the .csproj file.

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget.targets"/>
```

Where does something like this get set and how to I change it, or even remove it?

Where is *$(SolutionDir)* defined?

Comment: `SolutionDir` is the directory the .sln file is in, and is defined by visual studio. If you're building from the command line you can set it like any other property e.g. `msbuild Solution.sln /p:SolutionDir=new_dir`

Comment: I'm building from inside VS.NET, not command line.  This isn't a project I created.  I'm trying to move it to a completely different location and maybe keep the nuget program.  But just trying to understand how the nuget reference was created.

Comment: It was created by Nuget when the original programmer used it to add a library to his project.  It is *very* unclear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: What is unclear?  Besides editing the .csproj, I don't see any way to edit/remove this Import reference.  That is stated in the OP.  Also, when I try to open the project in a new location, it fails because nuget can't be found.

Comment: The original programmer used a common NuGet configuration step to ensure NuGet packages are restored when building. Perhaps the programmer neglected to add the nuget.exe and nuget.targets into your source control. See more: http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/02/24/nuget-tip-1-restore-packages-on-build/